# How to append email id for comma separated string in perl?

Tags: perl

I am looking for values like

```
$user = user1@email.com,user2@email.com,user3@email.com
```

However, I am getting `user1@email.com` only. Please suggest how to perform?

my code

```
$user = user1,user2,user3,;
$user =~ s/,+|,+$/\@email.com,/;
$user =~ s/,+$//;
```

Comment: Take a look at the `/g` modifier in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In keeping with your original intent:

```
$user = 'user1,user2,user3,';
$user =~ s/,/\@email.com,/g;
$user =~ s/,$//;
```

Another approach that has a slightly different flavor to it:

```
$user = 'user1,user2,user3,';
$user = join(',', map { $_ . '@email.com' } split(/,/, $user));
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't require the trailing comma (although it works with it):

```
$users = join ',', map { $_.'@email.com' } split /,/, $users;
```

If you need to remove empty fields, you can use the following:

```
$users = join ',', map { $_.'@email.com' } grep { length($_) } split /,/, $users;
```